# Transcendental numbers and irrationality measure

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible to generate transcendental numbers of arbitrary irrationality measure ? I am thinking of something like an infinite series which depends on a parameter fixing the irrationality measure.

All I have found so far is bounds on the irrationality measure of famous numbers, I have not been able to find something going the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using one of the results at the Wolfram MathWorld web page for [Irrationality Measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html), it's fairly straightforward to construct simple continued fraction expansions that represent real numbers having any preassigned real number $m \geq 2$ as their irrationality measure.

In particular, see Jonathan Sondow's paper [Irrationality Measures, Irrationality Bases, and a Theorem of Jarnik](https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0406/0406300.pdf).

Comment: This is exactly what I was after ! Thank you !

Comment: One point though, while I understand how to proceed for integer irrationality measure (with a_{n+1} = q_n^{m-2} ), how to you go for non-integer irrationality measures ?

Comment: Humm...maybe it's not straightforward! I see two issues. First, given any real number $m \geq 2,$ find a sequence $q_{1}, \, q_{2}, \, q_{3}, \, \ldots$ of positive integers such that $\frac{\ln q_{n+1}}{\ln q_n} \rightarrow m.$ Second, given any sequence $q_{1}, \, q_{2}, \, q_{3}, \, \ldots$ of positive integers, find a real number whose sequence of continued fraction convergents has a subsequence whose terms (when expressed as reduced quotients of positive integers)  have denominators of $q_{1}, \, q_{2}, \, q_{3}, \, \ldots$ Maybe ask [Sondow](http://home.earthlink.net/~jsondow/).

Comment: Ok, I think I can work something out from that. Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2207076/268333) to a duplicate gives a simple explicit construction.