# Is the irrationality measure function surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

Let $\beta>2$ be a real number, is it always possible to construct a real number $x$ such that $\mu(x)=\beta$? where $\mu$ denotes the irrationality measure.

---

The problem as I see it is to find $(a_n)_n$ an unbounded sequence of positive integers such that $\limsup \ln_{q_n}(q_{n+1})=\beta-1$ where $q_n$ is the numerator of the $n$-th convergent of $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\dots]$. But I was not able to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Irrationality measure more than 2 means having continued fraction with terms that grow mighty fast, so we'll have more than enough freedom for every next term.

Since $q_{n+1}=a_{n+1}q_n+q_{n-1}$, we might simply choose
$$a_{n+1}=\left\lceil\left(q_n^{\beta-1}-q_{n-1}\over q_n\right)^{1/(\beta-1)}\right\rceil$$

As $n$ and $q_n\to\infty$, so does $a_{n+1}$, which quickly makes the rounding error negligible.

Comment: $\mu(x)=2+\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(a_{n+1})}{\ln q_n}$. Here, if I'm not mistaken, that reduces to: $$\mu(x)=2+\frac{1}{\beta-1}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(q_n^{\beta-1}-q_{n-1})}{\ln q_n}-1\right)$$And I believe that this reduces to $2+\frac{\beta-2}{\beta-1}=3+\frac{1}{\beta-1}$, which doesn't suffice! I justify my believe by noting that $q_{n-1}\ll Nq_n$, due to the large choices of $a_n$, and has vanishing effect in the logarithm